# Reference request: Long-term behaviour of the heat equation for bounded initial data

Tags: reference-request, differential-operators, parabolic-pde, heat-equation

Let us consider the heat equation
\begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(t,x) & = \Delta u(t,x), \\
  u(0,x) & = f(x)
\end{align*}
on the whole space $\mathbb{R^d}$. If $f \in L^p := L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for $p \in [1,\infty)$ or if $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$, the long term behaviour of the solution $u(t) := u(t,\cdot)$ is well-known:

- If $f \in L^p$ and $p \in (1,\infty)$, then $u(t)$ converges to $0$ with respect to the $L^p$-norm and also with respect to the $L^\infty$-norm as $ t\to \infty$.
- If $f \in L^1$, then $\|u(t)\|_{L^1} \to |\int_{\mathbb{R^d}} f(x) \, dx|$ as $t \to \infty$, and we do not have convergence of $u(t)$ with respect to the $L^1$-norm, in general. However, we still have $\|u(t)\|_\infty \to 0$.
- If $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$, then also $\|u(t)\|_\infty \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

Now, I am interested in the long-term behaviour of $u(t)$ if $f \in C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$, i.e. if $f$ is a bounded continuous function. (*Note:* In this case, it is maybe less clear what we mean by a solution of the heat equation, but we can still define a "solution" $u(t)$ as the convolution of $f$ with the heat kernel).

Uniform convergence of $u(t)$ as $t \to \infty$ is probably too much to expect for many functions $f$, but I would be interested in locally uniform convergence:

**Question.** Is there a characterization of those $f \in C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for which $u(t)$ converges uniformly on compact sets to a constant function as $t \to \infty$?

I would expect that this has been studied somewhere in the literature, so my question is mainly a reference request.

**Disclaimer.** I discussed this question with a few experts on the matter, but they did not know the solution nor did they know a reference.

Comment: Your claim for the case $f\in L^1$ is incorrect. The $L^1$-norm is not constant, unless $f$was signed. Only the integral $m$ of $u(\cdot,t)$ is constant. In general, $t\mapsto\|u(t)\|_1$ is non-increasing and converges towards $|m|$. the solution is $L^1$-asymptotic to $mK_t$ where $K_t$ is the heat kernel.

Comment: Besides $\|u(t)\|_\infty\le(2\pi t)^{-d/2}\|f\|_1$ so that $u(\cdot,t)$ converges uniformly to zero.

Comment: I don't have a reference, but my inclination would be to look at $\partial_t u(t)$, which you can compute from the convolution formula by differentiating under the integral sign, and try to show it goes to 0 sufficiently fast (uniformly on compact sets) to force convergence of $u$.

Comment: @DenisSerre: You're of course right (I have a tendency of always thinking about the case $f \ge 0$ tacitly...). Corrected. Concerning the uniform convergence to $0$: yes; moreover, uniform convergence to $0$ also holds for $f \in L^p$, $p \in (1,\infty)$, since the operators of the heat semigroup map $L^p$ continuously into $C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$. I have also added this information to the post.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thank you for your comment. I'll have to think about it in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's quite a subfield in the theory of parabolic equations called stabilization of solutions (for large $t$). I'd recommend to start with the article of V. V. Zhikov, *On the stabilization of solutions of parabolic equations*, Math. USSR-Sb., 33:4 (1977), 519–537, for the exposition as well as for the earlier work references. He proves the  related results for the parabolic equations in divergence form. Afaik for the heat equation the condition is indeed the existence of the limit mean value in balls of the initial function, as proved in circa 1960s.

Comment: That's a great reference, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, with initial data in $C_b$, classical solution exist, so there is no need for quotation marks. It is easy to see that the convolution of the initial data $f(x)$ with the Gauss–Weierstrass kernel $p_t(x)$ defines the unique bounded classical solution $u(t, x)$.

It is easy to see that $u(t,x) - u(t,y)$ converges to zero as $t \to \infty$: the functions $p_t(\cdot - x) - p_t(\cdot - y)$ converge in $L^1$ to zero as $t \to \infty$. It is only slightly more difficult to see that this convergence is locally uniform with respect to $x$ and $y$. Therefore, your question is equivalent to the following simpler one: for what initial data $f(x)$, the limit of $u(t, 0)$ exists as $t \to \infty$.

I doubt there is a simpler "if and only if" characterization. One can easily provide sufficient conditions, for example it is sufficient to assume that the mean value of $f$ over the ball $B(0, R)$ has a limit as $R \to \infty$ (by the same argument that one uses when proving that Cesàro convergence implies Abel convergence). And one can equally easily construct counterexamples.

Comment: +1 The observation that the solution converges uniformly on compact subsets if and only if it converges at the point $0$ is really interesting. Of course, I would still hope for a characterization of those $f$, maybe as members of some kind of nice function space. (But I agree with you that this hope is somewhat bold.) Concerning the quotation marks around "solution": I only used them because $u(t)$ does not converge to $f$ with respect to the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$-norm as $t \downarrow 0$, so this notion of solution is slightly weaker that what one has, for instance, for $C_0$-semigroups.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that there is a characterization, but one thing I can say is that the complement of the set of such $f$ contains a dense open set.

Let $U(f)$ be the solution with initial condition $u(0,x) = f(x)$, and
$$G = \{f \in C_b: \lim_{t \to \infty} U(f)(t,\cdot)\ \text{converges uniformly on compact sets}\}$$

Take some $f_0 \in C_b$ such that $U(f_0)(t,0)$ does not converge as $t \to \infty$.  Let $\delta = \limsup_{t \to \infty} U(f_0)(t,0) - \liminf_{t \to \infty} U(f_0)(t,0) > 0$.  Then for any $f \in G$ and any $c \ne 0$, if $\|g- (f + c f_0)\|_\infty < |c|\delta/2$ 
then $$\limsup_{t \infty} U(g)(t,0) - \liminf_{t \to \infty} U(g)(t,0) \ge |c|\delta - 2 \|g-(f+c f_0)\|_\infty  > 0 $$

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer! Alternatively, one can also argue that $G$ is a proper subspace of $C_b$ that is closed with respect to $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, so its complement is an open and dense set.